# How to configure VNC in ubuntu 23.10

Tags: vnc

I tried a few instructions on google on how to config VNC, but I can't get it to work on 23.10 on PI 5. Can someone help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: You do not even specify what software it is you want ot use. VNC is a protocal. We help with concrete problems. So how far did you get? Remmina is a VNC (and a bit more) and is pretty straightforward; insert the correct info and it will works.

Comment: Have you tried the Gnome's built-in **Settings > Sharing** Tab on Left **> Remote Desktop > Enable Legacy VNC protocol**? You will need to login physically and manually first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried tigerVNC, TightVNC, and RealVNC and none of them work. When I VNC to it, it only gave me the grey screen.

Comment: On the Ubuntu 23.10, remote desktop does not have Legacy VNC protocol setting like 22.4.